# Houseplant identifying and growing conditions?

Tags: houseplants

[![enter image description here][1]][1]Can anyone identify this plant please because it had no information on its tag.
I also would like to know its growing conditions
How much water does it need?
Would it prefer bright and warm areas beacause that's not what it is receiving in its location at the moment?
And is it prone to a lot of diseases?

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [Dracaena reflexa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_reflexa) sometimes known as Pleomele reflexa and is native to Madagascar and areas around the Indian ocean.  It looks to be a well established specimen. 
In the wild they get quite large.

[image: Dracaena reflexa]

Indoors they will stay much smaller and prefer a bright diffuse light such as a south or west window behind light curtains.  They do not like to be overwatered so let the top two or three inches dry out before watering until water comes out the bottom of the pot.

It is rare for them to get any pests but this one a has nutrient deficiency which can be seen in the darker veins and lighter leaf area of the newer leaves.  This could be a manganese deficiency.  As this is an older plant I recommend removing it from the pot, adding fresh soilless mix as the bottom and removing some of the roots at the circumference.  A seaweed based fertilizer is a good alternative as they can be dilute but with many micro nutrients.